# Postgresql query is taking too long to execute

Tags: postgresql

```
let datamartQuery = {
    text: 'SELECT concat(datelist.year,datelist.hypen,datelist.month,datelist.hypen,datelist.day,datelist.hypen,datelist.hour) as date,nurse_ky as Nurse, bp as bp,spo2 as sp,hr as hr,rr as rr,temp as temp, patient.cpmrn as CPMRN FROM datelist,datamart,patient where patient.cpmrn in (select cpmrn from patient where patient.pid=datamart.pid)  and datelist.date_key = datamart.date_key and datelist.date_key between $1 and $2  ORDER BY date ASC',
    values: [start_date, end_date]
}
```

Comment: What's this? What are you expecting us to tell you? Please edit your question and add more details, things like table structure, the size of the tables, etc. can be very helpful.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.